# Rails escape things that can be auto linked by email client (Gmail, Outlook)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, gmail, escaping, actionmailer

When you're sending emails on rails, you often use `<%= variable %>` to inject data in the view.

Problem is, if the `variable` contains something like `http://google.com`, email clients will happily auto create a link for that string, even though you didn't wrap it around an `<a>` tag. That can lead to various security problems.

Now I don't want to try to find a solution for each case. So is there a simple trick that I can use on ActionMailer views to make sure that any potential url will not be autolinked by email clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a easy way like a setting to prevent that, since it's happening on the client side.

A way of deceiving the email clients is by adding `<span>`s in the middle of URLs, which prevents links to be added without changing the text style.

You can do that in specific places with a helper like:

```
module MailHelper
  def escape_links(text)
    h(text).gsub(/[\.:]/, '<span>\0</span>').html_safe
  end
end
```

And then use it in the view templates as `<%= escape_links variable %>`.

I agree it'd be a bit annoying having to add this everywhere, and it seems you want a more generic solution. In that case, something that might work (I didn't try it myself yet) is to apply similar approach using [email interceptors](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#intercepting-emails) to change the message body. You would need a smarter replacement strategy though to avoid adding `<span>`s inside `<a>`'s `href`s.

Comment: This is the closest I get to the best answer, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can add this css to your email.

```
*{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will prevent all mouse click on email as in html.

Comment: Thank you, but this will disrupt the normal real links I have on the email.